# How to retrieve checked values

Tags: go, beego

With this given HTML code I was able to add a simple javascript function to verify that at least one checkbox is checked.

Now it turns out that I only receive the value of the first checked checkbox, even when all three are checked.

**HTML**:

```
<label class="foo">
       <input type="checkbox" name="bar[]" value="W01">
       <span class="label-body">Apple</span>
</label>
<label class="foo">
       <input type="checkbox" name="bar[]" value="W02">
       <span class="label-body">Banana</span>
</label>
<label class="foo">
       <input type="checkbox" name="bar[]" value="W03">
       <span class="label-body">Melon</span>
</label>
```

**Controller**:

```
func (this *SendController) Post() {

    beego.Info(this.GetString("bar[]"))
    // ...
}
```

How can I get the list of all selected checkboxes, ie. W01 & W03?

Bonus question:
What is the difference between `this.GetString("foo")` and `this.Input().Get("foo")` ?

Comment: consider the GetString*s* method https://godoc.org/github.com/astaxie/beego#Controller.GetStrings. The second question relates to https://godoc.org/net/url#Values.Get. it does not look like there much of a difference between `this.GetString("foo")` and `this.Input().Get("foo")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get array parameters like this

bars := this.GetStrings("bar")

[beego params](https://beego.me/docs/mvc/controller/params.md)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.